# How do i print specific rows that meet the conditions?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to find out, is there a way I could print the rows that meet the condition I've set? I'm currently using iterrows() though I know it is not ideal, I have over 1000 rows of data I have to sift through and have not found any other way I can iterate through my data.

Here's a mock data:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1TlT.png

For example, I'm trying to find out if the +-3SD of the age range of two people overlap (I did not calculate the +-3SD here in the mock data but hope you are able to understand) And here's how I code it:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['last_name_x'] > row['last_name_y'] or row['last_name_x'] < row[last_name_y']:
```

And then I'm stuck. I want to allocate the id_x and id_y of those who meet the conditions above into a dataframe. The ideal output I would want would be as follows:

```
  id_x      id_y  
 0   Vyel      Vyel
 3   Vyel      Jinda
```

^ this is just an example of the dataframe I would want it to look like.

Do let me know if it's possible and how I can improve, thank you!

Comment: Try `df.query('last_name_x != last_name_y')[['id_x', 'id_y']]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df[df['last_name_x'] != df['last_name_y']][['id_x', 'id_y']]
```